# Naming humans after Gods/Devas

Tags: puranas, gods, name

At the present time, large numbers of Hindus are named after Gods - Rama,Krishna,Lakshmi,Parvati et al.

But in scripture - the practice seems to have only barely begun in the Puranas - the famous Narayana, the son of Ajamila who was instrumental in getting Ajamila to Vishnu-loka.

Any reasons why humans usually did not have Gods' , Devas' names before the Puranas?